# Using ICommand interface

Tags: c#, interface, instance, icommand

I have a class that implements specific interface (`IOrganicEnvironment<T, K>`)

```
public class Colorizator : IOrganicEnvironment<Cell<YUV>, YUV>, ICommand
{
    // ..
}
```

And also it implements ICommand iterface

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}
```

`IOrganicEnvironment<T, K>` interface provides a bunch of methods and properties I'm mostly going to use inside `ICommand Execute()` method.

But I don't need any client code to invoke that methods and properties from `Colorizator` instance.

What can/should I do? If I implement the interface `explicitly` and make it `internal` will this help?

Comment: Just to clarify: all clients should care about is the ICommand implementation and not IOrganicEnvironment<T,K>?  If this is so, it seems as though some code (although maybe not the "client") needs to know it satisfies IOrganicEnvironment<T,K> - can you tell us a little bit more about this? In any case, explicit interface implementation might help you here as you've wondered. The other thing I wonder about is if this is really the right layer to be implementing ICommand - it seems as though it's much deeper than a simple DTO layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using composition would be better idea.

```
public class Colorizator : IOrganicEnvironment<Cell<YUV>, YUV>>
{
   // normal code here
}

public class ColorizatorCommand : ICommand
{
    private Colorizator _colorizator;

    public ColorizatorCommand(Colorizator colorizator)
    {
        _colorizator = colorizator;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        //use _colorizator here;
    }
}
```